# Random Forest score ambiguity

Tags: machine-learning, regression, random-forest, evaluation, supervised-learning

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Za1PIjx3_14hZ3qYyEXmtqiQiHw3Mo_D/view?usp=share_linkWhy does random forest score differ from r2-score since random forest uses r2-score for evaluation?[enter image description here][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Nhv.png)
The reason two score are differing.

```
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators= 100, max_depth = 10, max_features='sqrt')
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred=rf.predict(X_test)
print(rf.score(X_test,y_test))
print(r2_score(y_pred,y_test))
```

output:
0.7111716587426178,
0.6246564690587202

Comment: Can you provide an example of input that produces this behavior?  We don't need *your* input, but it would be useful if we could reproduce the problem.  Are there any example datasets that cause a similar discrepancy?

Comment: [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.score) specifically state that "The score used when calling score on a regressor uses multioutput='uniform_average' from version 0.23 to keep consistent with default value of r2_score. This influences the score method of all the multioutput regressors (except for MultiOutputRegressor)."  Perhaps this is relevant.

Comment: @Him could you please elaborate multioutput regressors statement. I have data set that I would like to share.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason two score are differing

```
print(rf.score(X_test,y_test)) # X_test paired with y_test
print(r2_score(y_pred,y_test)) # y_pred paired with y_test ??
# output: 0.7111716587426178, 0.6246564690587202
```

The 0.624... score is likely a result of the mispairing / crossing streams.

In the first, you use `X-test` as the first argument, and `y_pred` as the first argument in the second line.

I know this is an old thread, but if you change your score calculations to be:

```
# test score:
print(rf.score(X_test,y_test))
print(r2_score(X_test,y_test))
# predict score:
print(rf.score(X_pred,y_pred))
print(r2_score(X_pred,y_pred))
```

I would expect the first 2 lines to produce the same output, and the second pair to produce the same output.